# React Hooks: Setting parent state before setting child state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've observed an interesting nuance of useState that I'm wanting to understand more deeply. The scenario:

- Parent component owns some some local state created via useState
- Parent passes an event handler function as a prop to a child component. This handler sets state in the parent.
- Child component also has local state created by useState
- When a certain event happens in the child, both the callback prop and the local state setter are called

My observation is that if the callback is run first, the a re-render of the parent is triggered which clobbers setting the child state. If I reverse the order things "seem" to be fine.

**Contrived example:**

Parent Component

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [, setParentData] = useState();
  function onData(data: string) {
    setParentData(data);
  }
  return (
    <Child
      onData={onData}
    />
  )
};
```

Child Component

```
const Child = ({
  onData
}) => {
  const [childData, setChildData] = useState();
  function onClick() {
    const data = Date.now;

    onData(data);

    // this call gets clobbered if onData is called first
    // but is fine if I swap them
    setChildData(data); 
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick}>{ childData }</div>
  );
};
```

Anyone know if ensuring child state setters are called before the parent callback is sufficient to keep all state updates, or are there other async types of things here where I may still have a race condition of some sort?

Comment: what do you mean by clobbered?

Comment: meaning it never gets set. It's looking like my contrived example doesn't actually have the issues, so I'm going to dig into my real use case and update accordingly

Comment: Interesting question, I'm facing the same problem